# Status of the solution of Hilbert's 16 problem (2nd part)

Tags: dynamical-systems, math-history, vector-fields

It is "known" that Écalle and Ilyiashenko (independently) solved the (first part of the) second part of Hilbert's 16th problem (i.e. they proved that the number of limit cycles of a polynomial vector field in the real plane is finite). However: apart from their respective books, is there any other more accessible proof?

I am an expert on the topic and I fear that both books are not read very much...